# Scraping unique links from website with Python only retrieving 1 link

Tags: python, web-scraping

I'm trying to scrape only unique urls from a website and write them to a file as absolute links.
WHen I initially scrape the site, I retrieve 253 links. However, when I use set() to retrieve only unique links and use code to turn them into absolute links, it only returns 1 url. I played around with it and removed the function unique_urls thinking that could be causing it, but it did the same thing. I'm new to Python and still grasping loops, so it could easily be something I've overlooked. Any ideas? Thank you.

```
import bs4
import requests
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup, SoupStrainer
import csv

url = "https://www.census.gov/programs-surveys/popest.html"
r = requests.get(url)
raw_html = r.text
soup = BeautifulSoup(raw_html, 'html.parser')
results = soup.find_all("a")

print ('Number of links retrieved: ', len (results))

def unique_urls(tags,url):
    cleaned_urls = str(link.get("href"))

for link in results:
    link = link.get("href")
    if link.startswith('/'):
        cleaned_urls.add('https://www.census.gov' + hrefs)
    elif link.startswith('#'):
        cleaned_urls.add(hrefs)
    else: 
        unique_urls.add(cleaned_urls)

print ('Number of links retrieved: ', len )
```

Comment: Before adding the `set()` you got 253 links, afterwards it returned only 1, and when you removed the `set()` to go back to what you first had, there was still only 1 result? Am I understanding that correctly? Can you provide a [mcve]?

Comment: No, sorry. When I removed the unique_urls function. Someone I know suggested I try it without the function, but I still used the set method. Not sure if that makes sense. When I get home, I can post an example. Thank you.

Comment: I don't understand the `unique_urls()` function, it takes two parameters which are unused, yet does use a variable which seemingly isn't defined anywhere. Neither of the functions here seem to return anything, it's probably best to refactor your code to take and return values, rather than messing with global variables.

Comment: Also, how do you define which links you're interested in?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

use below code for unique urls

```
import bs4
import requests
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup, SoupStrainer
import csv
import re

url = "https://www.census.gov/programs-surveys/popest.html"
r = requests.get(url)
raw_html = r.text
soup = BeautifulSoup(raw_html, 'html.parser')
results = soup.find_all("a")

print('Number of links retrieved: ', len(results))

list_urls = []
for link in results:
    link = link.get("href")
    if link is None or link == "#content":
        pass
    else:
        if re.match(r"https://", link):
            list_urls.append(link)
print("******* total urls*********")
print("total count of urls: ", len(list_urls))
print("*********** after unique*****")
unique_urls = set(list_urls)
print("length of unique urls:", len(set(list_urls)))
```

Comment: I went through the csv file and I think I should be getting 122 links, but only 92 are showing up.

Answer (score 0):

Is this what you require ?. I actually get only 92 valid and unique URL.

```
import bs4
import requests
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup, SoupStrainer
import csv
from functools import partial  
from operator import is_not


import re

filter_null = partial(filter, partial(is_not, None))

checklink = []

url = "https://www.census.gov/programs-surveys/popest.html"
r = requests.get(url)
raw_html = r.text
soup = BeautifulSoup(raw_html, 'html.parser')
results = soup.find_all("a")

print ('Number of links retrieved: ', len (results))

for result in results:

    checklink.append(result.get('href'))
    L =list(filter_null(checklink))

    regex = re.compile(r'http')

    selected_files = list(filter(regex.match, L))
distinctTitle  = (list(set(selected_files)))

#def unique_urls(tags,url):
#    cleaned_urls = str(link.get("href"))
#
#for link in results:
#    link = link.get("href")
#    if link.startswith('/'):
#        cleaned_urls.add('https://www.census.gov' + hrefs)
#    elif link.startswith('#'):
#        cleaned_urls.add(hrefs)
#    else: 
#        unique_urls.add(cleaned_urls)

print ('Number of Unique and cleaned links retrieved: ', len(distinctTitle))
```

Comment: I wrote a solution myself, and found 122 links. Can you share the result you get?